# Suppress errors on a live production zendframework 2 site

Tags: zend-framework2

I have just launched my first Zend framework 2 site on a live production site. The problem is that my errors are still being rendered on the web page. I know that I was supposed to hide these errors on a live site, but I have forgotten where I am supposed to go or what i am supposed to do to suppress the errors from being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of errors you're seeing.

It could be that you have 'display_errors' turned on in your php.ini for the server, in which case you should change that or add `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` or similar to your main `./public/index.php` file.

If you're seeing exceptions on ZF2 rendered error pages, then you may need to change the config values typically found in the `./Application/config/module.config.php` file under the `view_manager` key.

```
'view_manager' => array(
      'display_not_found_reason' => false,
      'display_exceptions'       => false,
      // Other settings
 )
```